# Given the adjacency matrix, how to calculate laplacian spectrum

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, laplacian

I'm trying to calculate a laplacian spectrum of an adjacency matrix.  I tried to look online/youtube but couldn't really find anything. 
I've added a couple of sample matrices here:
[Sample adjacency matricies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O77eo.png)

For matrix A, I calculated the eigenvalues to be:

E = {2.377,-2.247,-1.651,-.555,0,1.274,.802}

but after this step, I'm not too sure what to do.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but from my understanding, I multiply A*E to get the spectrum, resulting in:

{.802, -.849,-.973, 2.076, 0.130, -2.206, -0.425}

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix